# Drawing with mouse on a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can draw a sequence of lines with

```
    klicker = clicker(ax, ["event"], markers=["x"], **{"linestyle": "--"})
```

command. However, I need to draw separate lines on a matplotlib graph. How can I do so?